# Retorno 0 do HTTP

Tags: java, http

estou com um problema um pouco estranho..

Preciso retornar o status de alguns endereços web para a aplicação, então usei o código abaixo:

O algorítimo, recebe como parâmetro uma URL, então me retorna o status HTTP. Caso seja **200**, sei que ta tudo ok, **caso não**, eu trato dependendo do retorno..
Pois bem, quando passo como parametros alguns sites específicos ele me retorna o **valor 0** (Que não é nenhum status HTTP)

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Segue o codigo:

```
public static Integer verificarSistema(String enderecoUrl){
    Integer code =0;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(enderecoUrl);

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();   
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        in.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e){
        System.out.println("Erro ao criar URL. Formato inválido.");
    } catch (IOException e2) {     
    }
    return code;
}
```

Comment: Mude a sua variável code para 3 e teste com um site que antes estava retornando 0. O retorno funciona ou passa a ser três?

Comment: Olá Lucas, mudei.. e o retorno passou a ser 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema..

Acontece que na empresa onde eu trabalho, havia bloqueios de rede para determinados endereços, logo não era possível realizar a conexão

Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 1):

Então, conforme vimos no comentário, o erro retornado muda em função do valor alimentado inicialmente.
Não existe erro HTTP com código 0 ou 3. Os números que você está vendo são retornados pelo seu código ou sua biblioteca. Você precisa checar a documentação e realizar um debug para ver em que momento ele acontece.

Tente fazer isso com um site que você sabe que funciona e retorna 200. Depois veja com um que você sabe que não funciona.

Eu arriscaria a dizer que pode ser um erro de sintaxe, ou até mesmo na URL, visto que para retornar 0 ele nem mesmo entraria no bloco `try-catch`